# C program generate log on runtime

Tags: c++, gcc, gdb, trace

I have a program which takes a lot of time to crash.

Is it possible to run the program and trace what is happening into a file, like trus does?

Comment: What's wrong with `truss`? On Linux, you have `strace`, if it's not available.

Comment: Uh, use `truss` (Solaris & others) or `strace` (Linux) just like you said? What's your question?

Comment: Is compiled program, or do you have it's sources?

Comment: Or just wait till it crashes and analyse the core file (gdb on Linux / BSD, DRWatson on MSWindows)

Comment: i have the source, thanks, i'll try the strace.. the program is huge and it runs for 8 - 10 days until it crashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"It depends".

If the program is doing a lot of system calls, like being very I/O intensive, you can probably glean something useful from running it through `strace`. Otherwise, you might want to try profiling it and inspecting the profile. Note that profiling often requires that you are able to re-build the program to add the profiling instrumentation code.